# longtable side by side

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

I've two longtables and I'd like to place them side by side. Tabular environments work very well, but I think it is not possible to place longtable side by side (why?).

It needs to be a longtable or a similar package because the table will be longer than a page. Here is an example of the two tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\caption{First Results} \\
\hline
28\% & 33\% \\
22\% & 36\% \\
58\% & 49\% \\
4\% & 89\% \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\caption{Second Results} \\
\hline
24\% & 64\% \\
76\% & 22\% \\
2\% & 8\% \\
32\% & 55\% \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: If the tables you need are as narrow as you indicate, why not make a single `longtable` with twice as many columns?

Comment: Perhaps you should build only a large table within both tables inside and a gap enough wide for distinguish them.

Comment: Or I suggest to use `[twocolumn]` or `multicol` package.

Comment: @Symbol1 That would either require splitting the tables manually at page breaks or would typeset all of the first table in 2-columns followed by all of the second in 2-columns rather than side-by-side, wouldn't it?

Comment: @cfr It will, definitely. But combining columns together makes it difficult to delete or add a single row. I cannot tell which is better.

Comment: If the table is really really long, you can also typeset two tables on two pdfs and include them using `pdfpages`.

Comment: @Symbol1 That will also put them one after another. Every `\includpdf` issues a `\clearpage`.

Comment: @cfr I meant to typeset tables on the paper of size, say, 105*297 and include two logical pages on a physical page.

Comment: (If there is no way to disable `\clearpage`: include pages from two pdfs alternatively to make another pdf, and include two logical pages form the new pdf on a physical page.

Comment: in answer to the (why?) two longtables side by side would be the same as two flows of text separately page breaking side by side which also is not directly possible (it's often requested eg for bi-lingual texts, but not easy to do in tex)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a minimally-disruptive solution using just `longtable` as suggested by Mike Renfro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{longtable}{c|c|c|cp{.3\linewidth}c|c|c|c}
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Table \thetable\ First Results} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\stepcounter{table}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Table \thetable\ Second Results} \\
    \cline{2-3}\cline{7-8}
    & 28\% & 33\% & & & & 24\% & 64\% \\
    & 22\% & 36\% & & & & 76\% & 22\% \\
    & 58\% & 49\% & & & & 2\% & 8\% \\
    & 4\% & 89\% & & & & 32\% & 55\%\\
    \cline{2-3}\cline{7-8}
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: longtable solution]

However, it may be better to follow the advice in the [booktabs](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) documentation and add a bit more spacing, dispensing with vertical rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable,booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{longtable}{cc>{\hspace*{.01\linewidth}}c<{\hspace*{.1\linewidth}}cc}
    \caption{Results}\\
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{First Results} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Second Results}\\\midrule\endhead
    \bottomrule\endfoot
     28\% & 33\% & & 24\% & 64\% \\
     22\% & 36\% & & 76\% & 22\% \\
     58\% & 49\% & & 2\% & 8\% \\
     4\% & 89\% & & 32\% & 55\%\\
 \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: longtable and booktabs]

But you might also think about how to set out the information. If everything is a % result, you might put this in the table caption and then present the first and second results as raw numbers. In this version, I also use the [siunitx](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package to handle the numerical values nicely:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable,booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{longtable}{SS>{\hspace*{.01\linewidth}}c<{\hspace*{.1\linewidth}}SS}
    \caption{Results (\%)}\\
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{First} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Second}\\\midrule\endhead
    \bottomrule\endfoot
     28 & 33 & & 24 & 64 \\
     22 & 36 & & 76 & 22 \\
     58 & 49 & & 2 & 8 \\
     4 & 89 & & 32 & 55\\
 \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: siunitx, longtable and booktabs with rearranged content]